# How to have MySQL return lowest last price from the price column in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with lots of tables (10+), all structured with the following columns;

```
id
price
created_at
```

I am updating these tables every 5 minutes with current price data for my particular product.

What I need to do is to query all of the tables to return the last price, and then return the lowest price, and also the table it came from (or possibly just the table it came from).

So if I have the following tables;

```
store1
store2
store3...
```

I need to find which store has the lowest price for my product.

I can do this the hard way by returning the last price in a PHP variable and then do the comparison in PHP, but would rather do it with SQL if possible.

Seems it's impossible to include any sort of table using html or ascii text. Formatting gets stuffed up all the time. Here is some sampe data as an image which seems to be the only way I can provide it on this platform;

[Sample Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6aqP.png)

So I need to compare the last price (highest id or time) from all tables, and find the lowest of those. The query should return 501.09

Comment: you can use `min` function like this 
`select min(column_price) from table`

Comment: Do you have massive amounts of data, or why did you split this into several tables with the same structure to begin with?

Comment: Yes I have a large amount of data, not massive. The structure of the tables is needed to track price changes for the product over time.

Comment: provide a better table structure(s) and some example data..

Comment: @jerome I don't want the lowest price from any one table. I want tu use the last price from all tables and then find the lowest of those.

Comment: @CBroe massive amounts of data would not be an argument for splitting the data into multiple tables

Comment: can you provide a sample of your table with some data in it ?

Comment: `SELECT MIN(price) FROM ( SELECT price FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT price FROM table 2 .... ) AS prices` should help a little bit

Comment: @user1222302 just fix your schema. Your argument for multiple tables makes no sense.

Comment: @Strawberry I know, but beginners often think differently (and often have a wrong understanding of what a “massive” amount would be to begin with.) I wanted them to give us the justification (if any) for why this was split over different tables to begin with, instead of having a column identifying with store are record belongs to in a single table.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland That will return the lowest price of all time, but I want the lowest price at the last update. The tables are updated every 5 minutes.

Comment: @Strawberry If I were to change my Schema it would be one very large table with stupid amounts of data.

Comment: I'll have to update with structure etc. tomorrow as I have a meeting now. Haven't worked with StackOverflow much before, will take me a while to build the HTML structure to get the layout right.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(price) FROM ( SELECT price, created_at FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT price, created_at FROM table 2 .... ) AS prices WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTES`   should help you even a little bit better

Comment: FWIW I have the structure the way it is so I can easily calculate the average price from all tables along with sales volume from each store into a price_volume table. This is working perfectly and for the most part I only need the average which is what I've got, however I would also like to know which store has the lowest price at any point in time.

Comment: The stupid amounts of data approach sounds more sensible than your present solution

Comment: @Strawberry I may as well just use a flat .txt file rather than a database if I take your approach of using a single table only. Each of these tables is used specifically by other functions on the website.

Comment: I don't believe you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(price) FROM
(
     SELECT price FROM (SELECT price FROM store1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
     UNION
     SELECT price FROM (SELECT price FROM store2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
     UNION
     SELECT price FROM (SELECT price FROM store3 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
)
```

If I understand you correctly this is what you want.

Comment: Error
MySQL said: 

#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
SELECT MIN(price),store FROM (SELECT *,if(1,'store1','store1') as store FROM `store1`
UNION ALL
SELECT *,if(1,'store2','store2') as store FROM `store2`
UNION ALL
SELECT *,if(1,'store3','store3') as store FROM `store3`) as store;
```

Comment: what does `if(1,'store1','store1')` mean ?

Comment: `if(1,'store1','store1')` just write `store1` instead?

Comment: Again I can't see anything in your query that will return the lowest LAST price. MIN will return the lowest value in the entire table. I need to look at the LAST price in each table and then find the lowest of them. Again, these tables have a new record written every 5 minutes with the current timestamp, price and volume of sales.

Comment: if condition in mysql ,if true second value will return if not third value

Answer (score -1):

You can select all last prices from all table mapped like `tableName: price`

```
SELECT store1.`price` AS store1, store2.`price` AS store2
 FROM store1, store2 
ORDER BY store1.created_at DESC, store2.created_at DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Output will be something like:

```
store1  store2  
------  --------
50       42
```

You can generate query for all tables with PHP, make query, get all latest prices (for each table) as array, and then get lowest value from that array.